# Do passives triggers during a duel?

Tags: dota-2

When Legion Commander starts dueling against an enemy hero, do passives triggers during combat? And what about illusions (Manta Style, Chaos Knight, Phantom Lancer, etc.) and wards (Venomancer, Shadow Shaman, etc.), do they make combat damage during duel?

Comment: are you asking if subunits of a hero (illusions, wards, minions) are in any form effected by duel? then the answer is no afaik -> they do normal damage. or are you going deeper if the passive of the main hero does no longer get applied to the subunits? thats a good question. if we take beastmaster i am not sure